# How To Calculate kVA values in power analyzer meters?

Tags: power-meter

I am using a Schinder Electric PM2120 power analyser meter.

I record values with it every 15 minutes.
When I calculate values in kVA manually and compare them with the recorded values, I notice that a difference appears. Please explain to me why this is happening.

I used \$Root 3\times VLL_{Avg}\times I_{Avg}\$ to calculate using kVA.

Spreadsheet link: [record](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RM5FYNY-MI4P4MI4eUBHKIdF9vI3nQxmHG8h5KDYGH0/edit?usp=sharing)

The time, voltage, current, kVA, THD values are taken from the measurements made with the meter.

Comment: When you insert links, put them in using the "hyperlink" option, in order to shoten them. You may also want to learn how to use Mathjax.

Comment: @DanielTork thank you for your information next time I will do it.

Comment: Here is a useful link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question has been edited to more clearly indicate the \$\sqrt3\$ is the prefix and not plain ordinary 3. However, the principle for calculating VA based on using RMS values (rather than average values) remains the same.

3*V*I (or \$\sqrt3\$*V*I) is the correct formula for calculating VA if the voltage and current are RMS quantities but it seems you are using average values and these are likely to be average values of RMS values and so will give an error.

Consider 10 amps flowing for 1 second then zero amps for 9 seconds repeating. The average is clearly 1 amp. The RMS is somewhat different because you have to square then average then take the square root.

So 10 amps squared is 100 and this is averaged over ten seconds to be 10 amps squared. Take the square root and you find that the RMS is \$\sqrt{10}\$ amps and is substantially different to the average value of 1 amp.

Comment: Then how to calculate kVA value by Va, Vb, Vc and Ia, Ib, Ic values

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? @ind

Comment: RMS values can get by measuring instrument. So it gives Voltage and current values in each phases. Which means Vr, Vy Vb ( R Y B phases voltage) and Ir, Iy, Ib (R Y B phases current). By using these values how to calculate three phase kVA value?

Comment: Vr.Ir + Vy.Iy + Vb.Ib would give you that but most people assume it is a balanced load on a balanced supply hence 3*V*I.

Comment: Which means without root 3 right? 3*(Vr.Ir + Vy.Iy + Vb.Ib) ?

Comment: \$\sqrt3\$ converts from phase voltage to line voltage i.e. from Vr to Vry. The "3" in the previous equation is unrelated to the \$\sqrt3\$ value.

Comment: So what is that 3 ? I know Vll = root 3 * Vln but what is this 3 ? So balanced supply equation also you mention 3 not root 3.

Comment: The 3 is because it's a 3-phase system with 3 voltages and three currents and 3 lots of powers/VA.

Comment: I think some confusion comes from the fact that when you originally raised your question I missed the word "root" and only saw "3" hence I assumed it to be a 3 phase system. However, the same principle is involved - you make VA from RMS voltage multiplied by RMS current.