# kVA Calculation for Unbalance Loads with V and I Data

Tags: power

I Used Power Analyzer for calculating kVA manually and compare with meter kVA values. When I calculate kVA values, I got the same time V and I value. This load is unbalanced.

I calculate total kVA and individual phases kVA. Following equations I used.

**Total kVA = root(3) * (VAn*IA + VBn*IB + VCn*IC)**

**Phase kVA for A Phase = root(3) * (VAn*IA)**

But calculated values and power analyzer readings are different. Please tell me why is that and how to calculate it (Total and phase-wise)

Please tell me how to effect Neutral current for total kVA values and individual kVA values.

All Meter Data and Calculate Data Available in [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nYdqZ4MEvYMan6IMMcZGX5hMrjtvOEV09FhclFb4qBo/edit?usp=sharing)

Previously I calculate using average values but that is wrong. Those data available [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RM5FYNY-MI4P4MI4eUBHKIdF9vI3nQxmHG8h5KDYGH0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where are the primary values you use to do the calcs coming from - are you getting the full accuracy or just a displayed value? What is the measurement error? What is the result error?

Comment: Also see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/389802/152903

Comment: Are the voltages phase voltages with respect to neutral and are the currents phase currents?

Comment: Primary Values are in that sheet which is get by meter memory. (Data Log)

Comment: @Andyaka Accouding to sheet it has line voltages (VAB, VBC, VAC) and phase voltages (VAN, VBN, VCN). Current values are phase currents.

Comment: @Andyaka no body answer this question

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth on unbalanced loads.